# How can i use ".has_role?" from Rolify within Tabulous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have an app that uses Rolify, Devise, CanCan, and Tabulous.

In my `tabulous.rb` file, I want to be able to define the `Visibility?` of a tab by calling:

```
(current_user.has_role? :admin)
```

So the `config.tabs` do will look something like this:

```
# TAB NAME | DISPLAY TEXT | PATH | VISIBILE? | ENABLED?
[ :admin_tab, 'ADMIN' , ingredients_path , (current_user.has_role? :admin) , true ],
```

Which works fine for most of the pages EXCEPT for when I go into the `/users/sign_in` path; it returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing /Users/[myname]/Projects/[project-name]/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #24 raised:

undefined method `has_role?' for nil:NilClass
```

And line #24 just points to the `=tabs` call within the `applications.html` file.

I know the problem is that `/users/sign_in` doesn't have access to the `.has_role?` function.

**How can I make it so that the `tabulous.rb` file can use it?**

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this code and worked!

```
config.tabs do
  showTab = (current_user && (current_user.has_role? :admin))
  [
    [ :users_tab, "Users", users_path, showTab, showTab],
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, tabulous caches tabulous.rb when in production mode, so while your approach might work most of the time in development, it would break in production, and everyone would end up getting the same tabs, one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Karen. I worked around the issue a while back by reassessing the users' accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix can be done in `tabulous.rb file

```
[:admin_tab, 'Admin', users_path, current_user && current_user.has_role?(:admin), true],
```

`current_user` is not defined when the user is signed out, so you need to also check in `tabulous.rb` file if there is actually a `current_user` defined.